# Selecting maximal column's value doesn't provide desired results

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a table which is called `cities` and looks like so:

```
id | city | population | year
```

I simply need:

For each city select maximal amount of  population and year of that maximal population. A solution without nested queries is preferred

So I tried this:

```
SELECT `city`, MAX(`year`), MAX(`population`) FROM `cities` GROUP BY `city`
```

But it gives wrong results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need `MAX(year)` you just need `SELECT city, year, MAX(population) FROM cities GROUP BY city`

Comment: can you provide the sample output, like what you were expecting and what you got?

Comment: MySQL? Please tag, since MySQL has it's own ways...

Answer (score 2):

1st you have to take max population than you need take max year for that population . Try this:

```
SELECT C.city, max(C2.year), C.MAX_population
FROM 
(SELECT city, MAX(population) AS MAX_population FROM cities GROUP BY city) C
JOIN cities C2 on C2.city = C.city and C2.population = C.MAX_population
GROUP BY C.city, C.MAX_population
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without nested queries?